# Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I m using `Android Studio` v0.8.6

I have an `Android` app using `google-play-service` and I get this error when I try to build:

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :libraries:BaseGameUtils:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2.
     Required by:
         RIGHTER-android:app:unspecified
         RIGHTER-android:app:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11
         RIGHTER-android:app:unspecified > RIGHTER-android.libraries:BaseGameUtils:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2.
     Required by:
         RIGHTER-android:app:unspecified > RIGHTER-android.libraries:BaseGameUtils:unspecified
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2.
     Required by:
         RIGHTER-android:app:unspecified > com.github.filippudak.progresspieview:library:1.0.4

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.405 secs
```

This Error just happened recently and I didn't update a thing.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check in Android SDK Manager if you have installed Android Support Library 21.0.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to update the `Android SDK Manager` once in a while :-}

Answer (score 0):

AS I can understand my comment: "Can you check in Android SDK Manager if you have installed Android Support Library 21.0.2?" helped you.

But coming to core of issue. I think, that core of your issue was dependencies part in build.gradle. I strongly believe, that in:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:x.y.z'
```

you had somewhere '+', and it means, that version of library, that you are using is not set once, and can change, and this happened with Google Play Services Library.

Always try to put full version number of library, to not have this kind of issues in feature.

Comment: I have the same problem, in both cases with a specific version number, or with +. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just open the Android SDK manager and install the Android Support Library and the Android Support Repository.